# ElasticSearch: How to search on different fields that are not related that are arrays of objects

Tags: elasticsearch

***I want to search on different fields that are not related that are arrays of objects. I cannot find out how.***

Given the following mapping and data entry: I want to give the user the ability to search all possible fields in any combination. The user would use a form with a keyword input, exclude keyword input, date ranges and multi-select drop down lists. What does that query look like? I have included a couple of my failed queries and filters below the data entry.

**Mapping**

```js
{
    "plants" : {
        "properties" : {
            "name" : {"type" : "string"},
            "description" : {"type" : "string"},
            "planting" : {"type" : "string"},
            "maintenance" : {"type" : "string"},
            "type" : {"type" : "integer"},
            "petals" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "color" : {"type" : "string"}
                }
            },
            "species" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "name" : {"type" : "string"},
                    "subspecies" : {
                        "properties" : {
                            "name" : {"type" : "string"}
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "pests" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "pest" : {"type" : "string"}
                }
            },
            "diseases" : {
                "properties" : {
                    "disease" : {"type" : "string"}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Data Entry: Rose**

```js
{
    "name" : "Rose",
    "description" : "A few paragraphs of text",
    "planting" : "A few paragraphs of text",
    "maintenance" : "A few paragraphs of text",
    "type" : "Perennial",
    "petals" : [
        {"color" : "Red"},
        {"color" : "White"},
        {"color" : "Yellow"},
        {"color" : "Pink"},
        {"color" : "Orange"},
        {"color" : "Purple"}
    ],
    "species" : [
        {
            "name" : "Hulthemia",
            "description" : "A few paragraphs of text",
            "subspecies" : []
        },
        {
            "name" : "Hesperrhodos",
            "description" : "A few paragraphs of text",
            "subspecies" : []
        },
        {
            "name" : "Platyrhodon",
            "description" : "A few paragraphs of text",
            "subspecies" : []
        },
        {
            "name" : "Rosa",
            "description" : "A few paragraphs of text",
            "subspecies" : [
                {"name" : "Banksianae"},
                {"name" : "Bracteatae"},
                {"name" : "Caninae"},
                {"name" : "Carolinae"},
                {"name" : "Chinensis"},
                {"name" : "Gallicanae"},
                {"name" : "Gymnocarpae"},
                {"name" : "Laevigatae"},
                {"name" : "Pimpinellifoliae"},
                {"name" : "Cinnamomeae"},
                {"name" : "Synstylae"}
            ]
        }
    ],
    "pests" : [],
    "diseases" : []
}
```

**Query**

For example I have success with the following query, but it's not accurate on a large data set of 100k to 10M data entries (not flowers and MANY fields). I am searching on multiple fields that have multiple exact value matches while wanting to have a relevance score for each entry. The option for "minimum_should_match" does not make sense when I want flowers that "petal.color" are "purple", "pink" and/or "white" as well as searching against two more fields that are lists like "petals" or strings like "type". I could set "minimum_should_match" equal to two, but then **flowers with multiple "petal.color" will meet that requirement and I will get "type" that are not "Perennial" or "Annual" such as "Biennials"**. I looked into filter and have that as my next example.

```js
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query":"disease resistant",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                            "description",
                            "planting",
                            "maintenance",
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "tie_breaker":0.3
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not" : [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query":"lavender",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                            "description",
                            "planting",
                            "maintenance",
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "tie_breaker":0.3
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should" : [
                {"match" : {"type" : "Perennial"}},
                {"match" : {"type" : "Annual"}},
                {"match" : {"petals.color" : "purple"}},
                {"match" : {"petals.color" : "pink"}},
                {"match" : {"petals.color" : "white"}}
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Query using Terms**

The following is an attempt on using "terms". I'm not sure why it does not work.

```js
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query":"disease resistant",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                            "description",
                            "planting",
                            "maintenance",
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "tie_breaker":0.3
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms" : {
                        "type" : ["Perennial","Annual"],
                        "minimum_should_match" : 1
                    }
                },
                {
                    "terms" : {
                        "petals.color" : ["purple","pink","white"],
                        "minimum_should_match" : 1
                    }
                }
            ],
            "must_not" : [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query":"lavender",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                            "description",
                            "planting",
                            "maintenance",
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "tie_breaker":0.3
                    }
                }
            ],
            "should" : [

            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Query using Query/Filter**

The following is attempting to combine query and filter to use a mix of and/or filters. **I feel the issue is on "or" "petals.color" where "petals.color" is a list of colors and not an exact value.**

Another option is a permutation list of petals.color to solve the "or" issue (i.e. purple + pink + white, purple + pink, purple + white, pink + white, purple, pink, white.) That would get exhaustive on a list that can have hundreds of possible values and you're searching for a subset of them. Such as a list of countries and your matching only countries of a specific continent.

Another option is an inverse selection of "petals.color" and put in "bool" "must_not". This is less work than the permutation list as elasticsearch supports aggregates.

```js
{
    "query" : {
        "filtered" : {
            "query" : {
                "bool" : {
                     "must" : [
                        {
                            "multi_match":{
                                "query":"disease resistant",
                                "type":"cross_fields",
                                "fields":[
                                    "description",
                                    "planting",
                                    "maintenance",
                                    "name"
                                ],
                                "tie_breaker":0.3
                            }
                        }
                     ],
                     "must_not" : [
                        {
                            "multi_match":{
                                "query":"lavender",
                                "type":"cross_fields",
                                "fields":[
                                    "description",
                                    "planting",
                                    "maintenance",
                                    "name"
                                ],
                                "tie_breaker":0.3
                            }
                        }
                     ],
                     "should" : [
         
                     ]
                 }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "and" : [
                    {
                        "or" : [
                            {"match" : {"type" : "Perennial"}},
                            {"match" : {"type" : "Annual"}}
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "or" : [
                            {"match" : {"petals.color" : "purple"}},
                            {"match" : {"petals.color" : "pink"}},
                            {"match" : {"petals.color" : "white"}}
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nesting [bool][must][bool][should] isolating "minimum_should_match" to only the list (array of objects) being searched on. See the below example.

```js
{
    "query" : {
        "bool" : {
            "must" : [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query":"disease resistant",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                            "description",
                            "planting",
                            "maintenance",
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "tie_breaker":0.3
                    }
                },
                "bool" : {
                    "should" : [
                        {"match" : {"type" : "Perennial"}},
                        {"match" : {"type" : "Annual"}}
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match" : 1
                },
                "bool" : {
                    "should" : [
                        {"match" : {"petals.color" : "purple"}},
                        {"match" : {"petals.color" : "pink"}},
                        {"match" : {"petals.color" : "white"}}
                    ],
                    "minimum_should_match" : 1
                }
            ],
            "must_not" : [
                {
                    "multi_match":{
                        "query":"lavender",
                        "type":"cross_fields",
                        "fields":[
                            "description",
                            "planting",
                            "maintenance",
                            "name"
                        ],
                        "tie_breaker":0.3
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```